# Change location of geojson output using gdal

Tags: d3.js, leaflet, geojson, gdal, ogr2ogr

I was given a CAD file with no coordinate system, I converted the CAD file to the DXF format and then applied the source reference of 'epsg:3011' and the target reference of 'epsg:4326' when I converted the DXF file into geojson. This all resulted in my CAD elements being placed in Northern Russia when viewed in Leaflet, this is fine but I was wondering how I can change the location of my CAD elements to somewhere in China or Australia or Antarctica using ogr2ogr or one of the other GDAL tools?

Here is the orginfo for my DXF file:

```
Layer name: entities
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 6496
Extent: (-20.432717, -5.766225) - (665344.458898, 7453495.082726)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
Layer: String (0.0)
SubClasses: String (0.0)
ExtendedEntity: String (0.0)
Linetype: String (0.0)
EntityHandle: String (0.0)
Text: String (0.0)
```

Here is the command I used to create the GeoJSON:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -s_srs epsg:3011 -t_srs epsg:4326 temp.geojson inputFile.dxf
```

Here is the ogrinfo for my output geojson file:

```
Layer name: OGRGeoJSON
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 2456
Extent: (29.603788, 66.692900) - (29.695780, 66.741608)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9108"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
ogr_style: String (0.0)
```

Comment: You might want to look at this question on gis.stackexchange

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21256/how-to-easily-shift-all-features-in-a-vector-dataset

Comment: Thanks for tip Logan !